# perl passing array of hashes to a sub

Tags: perl, loops, hash, arguments, infinite

I'm passing an array  by reference to a sub `function(\@charts);`
the array charts contains hash array at i=0 and a string at i=1 and so on (hash-string..) 
I want to store the keys of hashes in @x and the values in @y as shown in the below function.But I'm getting an infinite loop;it keeps printing ...

```
sub function{
print Dumper @_;

    for ($i=0;$i<scalar @{$_[0]} ;$i+2)
    {
    @data= @{$_[$i]};
    $title=$_[$i+1];
    %hash =%{$data[$i]};
    # print Dumper \%hash;
    foreach my $key (sort { $a <=> $b} keys %hash) {
        push (@x,$key);
        push (@y,$hash{$key});
    }

     print Dumper @x;

    }}
```

Output:

```
 $VAR1 = [
   {
     '84' => 2,
     '11' => 2,
     '53' => 2,
     '3' => 2,
     '-46' => 2,
     '14' => 2,
     '-7' => 2,
     '47' => 2,
     '-10' => 2,
     '0' => 2,
     '72' => 2,
     '-2' => 2
   },
   '1_-2_-2'
 ];
```

## here is the @x infinite loop

```
 ...$VAR21817 = '-46';
    $VAR21818 = '-10';
    $VAR21819 = '-7';
    $VAR21820 = '-2';
    $VAR21821 = '0';
    $VAR21822 = '3';
    $VAR21823 = '11';
    $VAR21824 = '14';
    $VAR21825 = '47';
    $VAR21826 = '53';
    $VAR21827 = '72';
    $VAR21828 = '84';
    $VAR21829 = '-46';
    $VAR21830 = '-10';
    $VAR21831 = '-7';
    $VAR21832 = '-2';
    $VAR21833 = '0';
    $VAR21834 = '3';
    $VAR21835 = '11';
    $VAR21836 = '14';
    $VAR21837 = '47';
    $VAR21838 = '53';
    $VAR21839 = '72';
    $VAR21840 = '84';
    $VAR21841 = '-46';
    $VAR21842 = '-10';
    $VAR21843 = '-7';
    $VAR21844 = '-2';
    $VAR21845 = '0';
    $VAR21846 = '3';
    $VAR21847 = '11';
    $VAR21848 = '14';
    $VAR21849 = '47';
    $VAR21850 = '53';
    $VAR21851 = '72';
    $VAR21852 = '84';
```

Where is the problem and how to fix ? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The infinite loop is because of this line

```
for ($i=0;$i<scalar @{$_[0]} ;$i+2)
#                             ^^^^---- here
```

This is the loop incrementor, and you are just feeding it a number, not incrementing `$i`. This part should of course be `$i += 2`.

This is a rather poor setup, though. I assume `\@charts` looks something like this

```
$VAR1 = [
          {
            'a' => 1,
            'b' => 2
          },
          'foo',
          {
            'y' => 13,
            'x' => 12
          },
          'bar'
        ];
```

What you should do is keep the sets together

```
$VAR1 = [
          {
            'title' => 'foo',
            'data' => {
                        'a' => 1,
                        'b' => 2
                      }
          },
          {
            'title' => 'bar',
            'data' => {
                        'y' => 13,
                        'x' => 12
                      }
          }
        ];
```

That way you can simply assign directly, and use a simple loop

```
for my $href (@_) {
    my $title = $href->{title};
    my %hash  = %{ $href->{data} };
    ....
}
```

You should also add

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

And declare your variables in the smallest scope possible, such as inside a loop in a subroutine.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I changed the set up as u wrote , but when trying to access the $title and %hash I got this error "Not a hash reference "

Comment: That means you did not send a hash reference.

Comment: in fact I was sending it this way function(\@charts); the dumper was like [{{},{},{}}]. things are fixed when I removed the '\' and the dumper gives {{},{},{}}. though I dunno why for is all this confusion. Thanks a lot for your help